# How to Properly Use a Cloned Rails Project

Tags: git, clone, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Recently, I set up a new dev machine. To get it to seamlessly work with my other machine, I used Git to put my project on BitBucket. Then, I cloned it to my new machine. However, running `rails s` on the new machine gives me the following error:

```
/home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require': /home/XXXXX/rails/birch-paper-and-home/config/application.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/XXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This does not happen on my other machine.

After doing a bit of research, I found this is related to cloning a Rails Git repository. However, I have not found the solution to my problem. How can I get this project working on my new machine?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this machine using the same versions of Ruby and Rails?

Comment: Yes, they are. Luckily, I have found my answer. It appears a syntax error appeared after cloning the project. Recloning it fixed it.

Comment: If your question is answered, you should add your fix as an answer to this question and mark it as accepted.